# How to set a custom location as SuggestedStartLocation of filepicker/folderpicker

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

As windows store apps runs in so called sand-boxed environment,I decided to use folderpicker to get access to files.
I wanted to show the user his %localappdata% folder when file/folder picker is launched(C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local)
I couldn't find a way to do this or to set any custom location ("C\testFolder") instead of through setting predefined **PickerLocationId** enumeration.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible. WinRT doesn't have any provision to set ANY folder as `SuggestedStartLocation`.

Comment: For the time being this might be seen as a security issue. However, I think this might change as available disk resources are more easily enumerated by the developer. But for now, nope.